# Azure storage blob stream to dataframe error

Tags: python, azure, python-xarray

I am trying to stream netcdf file from azure blob storage to desktop without downloading to hard drive.
This is what i did:

```
import logging
import azure.functions as func
import xarray as xr
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient,BlobClient,ContainerClient
import requests
import io
connect_str="connection string"
blob_service_client=BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connect_str)
container_name = "cdspressure"
blobname="1000-temperature.nc"
container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(container_name)
blob1=container_client.get_blob_client(blobname).download_blob()
df=xr.open_dataset(blob1)
```

I get following error:

```
Executed 'Functions.xarray' (Failed, Id=aac8a675-f735-438e-a979-fffd3ac900df, Duration=6994ms)
System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Functions.xarray. System.Private.CoreLib: Result: Failure
Exception: AttributeError: 'StorageStreamDownloader' object has no attribute 'tell'
Stack:   File "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Azure Functions Core Tools\workers\python\3.7/WINDOWS/X64\azure_functions_worker\dispatcher.py", line 345, in _handle__invocation_request
    self.__run_sync_func, invocation_id, fi.func, args)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\concurrent\futures\thread.py", line 57, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Azure Functions Core Tools\workers\python\3.7/WINDOWS/X64\azure_functions_worker\dispatcher.py", line 480, in __run_sync_func
    return func(**params)
  File "C:\Users\terao\Documents\CatCom\CatCommand\CatCommand\xarray\__init__.py", line 13, in main
    df=xr.open_dataset(blob1)
  File "c:\Users\terao\Documents\CatCom\CatCommand\CatCommand\.venv\lib\site-packages\xarray\backends\api.py", line 536, in open_dataset
    engine = _get_engine_from_magic_number(filename_or_obj)
  File "c:\Users\terao\Documents\CatCom\CatCommand\CatCommand\.venv\lib\site-packages\xarray\backends\api.py", line 115, in _get_engine_from_magic_number
    if filename_or_obj.tell() != 0:
```

Any help in resolving this is appreceated. Thanks in advance

Comment: I managed to get it working localy with adding '.readall()' after '.download_blob()' . But when uploading to cloud stillnot working.

Comment: Could you please describe it in detail? What do you mean  `when uploading to cloud stillnot working`?

Comment: I wanted to say: not working when running function from cloud . My mistake. Meanwhile, I found out why is this not working. I am missing some 500 MB of memory in azure func. My blobs are about 600 MB in size. I guess ill have to go with premium plan in order to run this on Azure. Or to optimize memory consumption somehow.

Comment: I think you can try to download the large blob in the chunk  with `download_blob(offset=None, length=None, **kwargs)` then we will not read all content into memory at the same time.